# jQuery : Create new text box when the last textbox is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dynamic

I am building a form where the user can input the necessary tools to perform a task. I generate two input boxes for the user to have initially, but i want them to be able to have more inputs if necessary. I created a bit of jQuery that adds a new text box when the last text box is clicked, hinting that they may need another one. The code is as follows:

```
$( ".sidebar input:last-of-type" ).click(function(){
    $( ".sidebar input:last-of-type" ).after( '<input type="text" placeholder="Tool Name" />' );
});
```

This works, but it is only tied to the second text box that was generated initially. What I want to happen is if after the user adds additional tools, each time they click in the last, newly generated input, it will generate another one and so on. My guess is that the DOM still thinks that the second text box is the "last", although another one was added after the DOM was initially created. Is there a way to re-render the DOM or change my jQuery so that it ALWAYS selects the last input box?

Comment: Could you put a semi-working example on JSfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically added content can't be used with `.click()`. You need to use `.on("click")` on the parent element, `.sidebar`, and specify the child selector as the second argument.

```
$( ".sidebar" ).on("click", "input:last-of-type", function(){
    $( ".sidebar input:last-of-type" ).after( '<input type="text" placeholder="Tool Name" />' );
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cluxe/rzc13rto/1/)**

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for. So why is it that you can't use just the click() function of jQuery? I'd like to understand the why of the problem :)

Comment: @dge888 - From what I can tell, `.click()` binds itself when the page first loads. `.on("click")` with a child selector works because the child does not necessarily need to be loaded with the page. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "input" ).on('click' , addNewInput);

function addNewInput (){
  if($(this).is(':last')){
    $( this ).after( '<input type="text" placeholder="Tool Name" />' );
    $( "input" ).on('click' , addNew);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yann86/3xh09wab/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which looks for key presses as well as clicks (assuming people might be tabbing). The $('.sidebar').on is required as the :last input is dynamic and this is how you can target on dynamic content.

```
$('.sidebar').on( 'keypress click' , 'input:last-of-type' , function(e){
    $(this).after('<input type="text" placeholder="Tool Name" />') 
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nlaffey/fsuo5rmg/